# How would I prove that n^2 is O(n!) in terms of witnesses

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics

How would I use c and n0 to prove this relationship where n0 - 1 and c are NOT witnesses, I can't think of a pair that would satisfy this relationship.

Comment: I don't know what a witness is, it doesn't seem like standard notation? Also you can type mathematics with Mathjax. You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?
For $c=1$ we have
$$
n^2 < n!\qquad\text{for all }n \ge 4
$$
but
$$
3^2 \not< 3!
$$

Comment: Yes! Thank you. How would you go about getting this solution?

Comment: Write down $n^2$ and $n!$ for the first few values of $n$.  Then (from that evidence) guess that $n^2/n!$ decreases from that point on.  Prove it by induction.  But finding the exact starting point $n_0 = 4$ is just by writing down the first few values, since solving an equation with $n!$ in it is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction that $n^{2} \leq n!$ for $n \geq 4$. Here, $n_{0} = 4$ and $C = 1$.

Note that this only provides that $n^{2} \in O(n!)$. It does not show that $n^{2} \not \in \Theta(n!)$. To obtain that $n^{2} \not \in \Theta(n!)$, you would want to use the limit comparison test. Namely, show that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{n!} = 0.
\end{align*}

This implies that $n^{2} \in o(n!)$. So you obtain that $n^{2} \in O(n!)$ and $n^{2} \not \in \Theta(n!)$.